# How do you map / mount at network drive as the system user?

Tags: windows-server-2008, samba, wsus

We need to relocate our WSUS database to a network share (Samba no Kerberos, so it needs a username & pass).  Ordinarily to access the share I would map it as a network drive, however since this is a server and needs to run without a user logged on, I can't figure out how to map/mount the drive.

So how do you map a drive using the Windows System account, so that you don't need a logged on user?

Is iSCSI the only way?

Info:  using Samba 3.x & Windows 2008 x86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently iSCSI was the only way.